# Data structure for counting bits set on a table

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees

I have a table that contains only bits. I would like to be able to do the following two queries:

- SET any bit to 0 or 1;
- GET the number of bits that are set to 1 from the beginning of the table up to a specifique index i.

Is there a data structure that is more efficient than a [binary indexed tree](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Fenwick_tree), i.e. a Fenwick tree? A binary indexed tree performs both operations in $O(\log n)$ time, where $n$ is the number of elements.

For practical info, my tables are really large, containing up to millions of elements.

Comment: For a practical implementation, one could experiment with a bitvector, or maybe a (dynamic) array of say 64-bit words. There are very fast bit counting methods available, see e.g. [SSE4 popcnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT). Of course theoretically, the GET operation requires linear time. Real performance will however depend on size of $n$.

Comment: @Juho, I am not sure you can play with the index i using popcnt. I will add a precision in the Question a precision about n

Comment: Not directly. Depending on what $i$ is, you can first popcount enough words, and then start counting bits one-by-one when you hit the right word, if you see what I mean. And also, if you want, you can increase the bit level parallelism by counting in parallel with AVX2 vector registers.

Comment: Yes I understood what you mean. But this won't be good for a small $n$ as the number of words will be small. And it won't be efficient of large $n$ since it will only add a factor of 1/64 in front of the linear complexity. However it may be a solution for medium range tables...

Comment: What is your space complexity constraint?

Comment: @emab As I said $n$ may be in the order of millions. So a quadratic space is already a hard limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the operations is much more common, you could use an array of bits resp. of counts, so the common operation can be done in $O(1)$ at the cost of the other operation taking $O(n)$.

If you can't make such an assumption, then I don't think there is anything better than the $O(\log n)$ of the BIT.